# How to monitor progress of conversion, PDF to JPG with Imagick?

Tags: php, progress-bar, imagick

I am using PHP exec() for -convert Image Magick command, and i want to convert more than one page.

Given that it may take a few minutes, I need some kind of progress bar in order to monitor conversion.

Any ideas how I could done this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well you can not really track the progress of a single conversion. but you could for exmaple do something like the following when you want to convert multiple documents:

- the number of pages = 100%
- current page number / number of pages * 100 = progress in percent

so after each processed page you can update the progress.
you can write the info in a file or in a database (linked to the user session for a multi-user software) and poll for the status with an ajax reqeust to a php script which reads this file/db.

Comment: Something similar I had in mind, but I wanted to verify if there is other solutions. Thank you so much I think I'll apply that.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for this problem is message queues. I forked a code example of how to use Pheanstalkd (a PHP framework for beanstalkd) [here](https://gist.github.com/funkytaco/5833737)

This example shows how to have a sender that puts jobs in queue, worker that pulls jobs from queue, and a watcher that watches jobs (this part essentially does what you are asking for).

You can download Pheanstalk from [here](https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk)